# how to check the string ends with space in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, ends-with

I want to validate if the string ends with space in JavaScript. 
Thanks in advance.

```
var endSpace = / \s$/;
var str = "hello world ";

if (endSpace.test(str)) {
    window.console.error("ends with space");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`\s` represent a space, there is no need to add `[space]` in the regex

```
var endSpace = /\s$/;
var str = "hello world ";

if (endSpace.test(str)) {
  window.console.error("ends with space");
  //return false; //commented since snippet is throwing an error
}
```

```js
function test() {
  var endSpace = /\s$/;
  var str = document.getElementById('abc').value;

  if (endSpace.test(str)) {
    window.console.error("ends with space");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="abc" />
<button onclick="test()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith). It will be faster than `regex`:

```
myStr.endsWith(' ')
```

> The `endsWith()` method determines whether a string ends with the characters of another string, returning `true` or `false` as appropriate.

If `endsWith` is not supported by browser, you can use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill) provided by MDN:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
        var subjectString = this.toString();
        if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
            position = subjectString.length;
        }
        position -= searchString.length;
        var lastIndex = subjectString.lastIndexOf(searchString, position);
        return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
    };
}
```

Comment: What if I am checking to see if it ends with a space and 1 character? For example: `John R` matches but `John Ron` doesn't match.

Comment: @Si8 Use regex. `/\s.$/`. To allow only alphabet at the end `/\s[a-z]$/i`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var endSpace = / \s$/;
```

In the above line you are actually using 2 spaces, one is () and the second one is `\s`. That is the reason, your code is not working. Remove one of them.

```
var endSpace = / $/; 
var str="hello world "; 
if(endSpace.test(str)) { 
 window.console.error("ends with space"); return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code snippet -

```
if(/\s+$/.test(str)) {
   window.console.error("ends with space");
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also:

```
var str="hello world ";
var a=str.slice(-1);
if(a==" ") {
        console.log("ends with space");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#butCheck").click(function() {
    var checkString = $("#phrase").val();
    if (checkString.endsWith(' ')) {
      $("#result").text("space");
    } else {
      $("#result").text("no space");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id="phrase"></input>
<input type="button" value="Check This" id="butCheck"></input>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help to start and end white space in the string.

```
let begin_space_exp = /^\s/;
let end_space_exp = /\s$/;
/* Check for white space */
if (begin_space_exp.test(value) || end_space_exp.test(value)) {
  return false;
}`
```

I found /^\s+$/ has "AND" conditon like this
begin_space_exp.test(value) && end_space_exp.test(value)
then both should be true.

else you can use

```
(/^\s+|\s+$/g).test(value);
```